# Is the empty lattice a complete lattice?

Tags: order-theory

Is the unique lattice on the empty set, also a complete lattice? More precisely, $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ is the empty ordering, which is also a lattice. Is it also a complete lattice?

Comment: No. Complete lattices need top and bottom elements. (I also wouldn't call the empty poset a lattice; for me lattices should also have top and bottom elements.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: if your lattices have to have tops and bottoms, then your lattices are other people's **bounded** lattices.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Apologies for my careless reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the empty lattice is indeed a lattice - vacuously: any two elements have least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds and these behave the way they should - it is not, however, complete: the emptyset has no least upper bound, or greatest lower bound.

Note that complete lattices are *bounded*: the least upper bound of the emptyset has to be the minimal element, and the greatest lower bound of the emptyset has to be the maximal element.

Comment: Whether the empty set is a lattice depends, I guess, on whether you consider a lattice to be a kind of ordered set or a kind of algebraic structure.

Comment: @bof How do you mean? In some contexts, we allow algebraic structures to be empty (and it sounds like the OP is working in such a context).

Comment: You learn something new every day. I learned two things today: that the universe of an algebraic structure can be empty, and that "emptyset" is just one word. Sadly, I probably forgot more than two things today that I used to know, and I don't know what they are.

Comment: @bof: "empty set" is two words. And whether or not an algebra can have an empty carrier set is a moot point. I think most writers on universal algebra disallow this, e.g.  See https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for the reference!

Comment: It was a surprise for me to learn that the empty set can equip with a [group structure.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/heap#empty)

Comment: @Bumblebee That's not a group really - as they say, that's a *generalization of* the usual notion of a group. Because of the requirement that there be an identity element, groups cannot be empty.